# How to get a UITableView bigger in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Currently i am subclassing `UITableViewController`. I have made each cell in the `UITableviewController` bigger by implementing two methods.

**Code:**

```
(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

   CGFloat screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
   return screenHeight * 1/2;
}

(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   CGFloat screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
   return screenHeight * 1/2;
}
```

**I have Two problems/ questions**

1. my table seems to get very slightly pushed to the right , how can i fix this?
2. Is This the correct way to to make a UITableViewControllers Cell bigger? 
   also: if i make a custom cell, Cant i just put the custom cell in place of one entire                                cell so that , then it wouldn't matter what the height of the cell is? since, its being replaced by the custom cell?

Any advice would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want every row to be the same height then do no implement the two methods that you have. Instead, simply add the following line in `viewWillAppear:`:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = self.tableView.bounds.size.height / 2.0;
```

Also note that the height is based on the table view's height, not the screen height. This ensures that two cells will fit within the visible portion of the table view.

Only implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` if there are rows with different heights.

FYI - None of the code you posted would has any affect on the table seeming to be pushed to the right. That must be caused by something else.

Another note - keep in mind that `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` will give you the wrong results under iOS 7 or earlier if the device is in landscape orientation.

Comment: As Maddy says, you should not implement the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method unless you need your cell heights to vary between cells. (Voted) Implementing that method can slow down scrolling pretty significantly, especially if the table view is displaying a large data set (lots of rows of total data, not the number of rows on-screen at any one time.)

Answer (score 0):

To change the height of a UITableViewCell, you need simply to set the heightForRowAtIndexPath function. When creating a custom cell it will still be restricted to the size defined by the above function.

Answer (score 0):

Pertaining to your **problem number 2**, yes if you are replacing your cells with custom cells you don't need to implement the height delegate methods since you will already have that set in your custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS8 you can set your row height like this to get automatic heights for your cells (If you have setup constraints)

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44 //or your estimated row height
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```